# How to reverse piping properly?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, pipe

I try to do reverse piping. More precisely, I try to reverse this statement:

> echo 'user:passwd' | sudo chpasswd

I would like to get the 'sudo chpasswd' upfront. I tried both this:

> sudo chpasswd < echo 'user:passwd'

And:

> sudo chpasswd <(echo 'user:passwd')

Both won't work, and especially the last one I don't understand.

Is it possible to do what I want? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The following works on Ubuntu 17.10 using bash 4.4.12:

```
sudo chpasswd < <( echo 'mtak:password' )
```